# Zend Framework: How to include an OR statement in an SQL fetchAll()

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am trying to build the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT `users_table`.*, `users_data`.`first_name`, `users_data`.`last_name`
FROM `users_table`
INNER JOIN `users_data` ON users_table.id = user_id
WHERE (users_table.username LIKE '%sc%')
OR (users_data.first_name LIKE '%sc%')
OR (users_data.last_name LIKE '%sc%')
```

I have the following code at the moment:

```
public function findAllUsersLike($like) {
    $select = $this - > select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART) - > setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $select - > where('users_table.username LIKE ?', '%'.$like.'%');
    $select - > where('users_data.first_name LIKE ?', '%'.$like.'%');
    $select - > where('users_data.last_name LIKE ?', '%'.$like.'%');
    $select - > join('users_data', 'users_table.id = user_id', array('first_name', 'last_name'));
    return $this - > fetchAll($select);
}
```

This is close, but not right as it uses `AND` to add the extra `WHERE` statements, instead of `OR`.

Is there any way to do this as one select? Or should I perform 3 selects and combine the results *(alot more overhead?)*?

P.S. The parameter `$like` that is past is sanitized so don't need to wory about user input in the code above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function findAllUsersLike($like) {
    $select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)->setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $select->orWhere('users_table.username LIKE ?', '%'.$like.'%');
    $select->orWhere('users_data.first_name LIKE ?', '%'.$like.'%');
    $select->orWhere('users_data.last_name LIKE ?', '%'.$like.'%');
    $select->join('users_data', 'users_table.id = user_id', array('first_name', 'last_name'));
    return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if the first where could be a `orWhere` so I tested it, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I thought it would be where rather than orwhere - but like you say it doesn't seem to matter! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Zend_Db_Select has a function `orWhere`. You should be able to solve your problem with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also nest OR statements using double quotes ("):

> $select->where('
>   users_table.username LIKE ' "%'.$like1.'%" '
>   OR users_data.first_name LIKE '"%'.$like2.'%" '
>   OR users_data.last_name LIKE '"%'.$like3.'%"'
>   );

Which works better when you create sql including also AND like:

> select X from Y where A = AAA and (B = BBB or C = CCC or D = DDD)